# Phonegap Push plugin throughing 401 error when sending message through PHP

Tags: php, cordova, push-notification, google-api-php-client, phonegap-pushplugin

I tried this code.

```
function sendNotification( $apiKey, $registrationIdsArray, $messageData )
{   
    $headers = array("Content-Type:" . "application/json", "Authorization:" . "key=" . $apiKey);
    $data = array(
        'data' => $messageData,
        'registration_ids' => $registrationIdsArray
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers ); 
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data) );

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

And to call this function:

```
$message      = "the test message";
$tickerText   = "ticker text message";
$contentTitle = "content title";
$contentText  = "content body";

$registrationId = 'APA91bEgsAG3vmliDnJE7jfLAOGSUv3K9p41MkNranPFV4EY0svABRax8NY5oulOHv7s3v2Ks_bQutsLLw8j4mHOr5LkrRlFfXxfs3hxxwAlxIOG7cXCB4YPhlLCDspVtImyWBL_znGgkZzEWCncV3tidHMV'; (Id is wrong here for security reasons)
$apiKey = "AIzaSyD6kZoY3Qb_1ut57IEmwdRg0JuxC42W1"; (Key is wrong here for security reasons)

$response = sendNotification( 
                $apiKey, 
                array($registrationId), 
                array('message' => $message, 'tickerText' => $tickerText, 'contentTitle' => $contentTitle, "contentText" => $contentText) );

echo $response;
```

And now i am stuck. I just create a PHP page with my own registration id of device and google API key.

But it shows me error of:
Unauthorized
Error 401

When i run this URL http://vbought.com/sendnotification.php

i even added my server IP and domain name in the GCM reference

*.vbought.com/*

*.vbought.com

50.87.3.82

is there something i did wrong? Or i need to know? I am just trying to send one message to my only device.

Thank you! (in advance)

Comment: I think the curl is problem. Is there any way to get out of it?

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer. And the answer is i dont need to define anything in GCM. Like i defined my domain name and IP address. So i dont need to do anything. Just leave it blank and it will work like charm...

have a nice day :)